# verticaSDK.jar and BuildInfo.java files needed

Tags: vertica

Can someone guide me from where I can download VerticaSDK.jar and BuildInfo.java?

I Do not have access to Vertica Server and I was hoping to build UDX using eclipse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little roundabout (it would be better if those were posted, like the client drivers are), but if you don't have access to the Vertica installation you'll be working with, you can [download the community edition](https://my.vertica.com/download/vertica/) at no charge and pull them out of the RPM.

See [this documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ExtendingVertica/UDx/DevEnvironment.htm) about OS and SDK-version compatibilities.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I downloaded debian distribution and extracted the required binaries using 7z.